# How to get EF Core model snapshot for a specific migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-6.0

The question is only about EF Core 6 or above.

Let's say that I have two migrations in my project, call them `InitialMigration` and `SecondMigration`. The model snapshot contains information about the state of the database after both `InitialMigration` and `SecondMigration` were applied.

How can I determine the state of the database (model snapshot ???) if only `InitialMigration` were applied?

One may wonder why do I need that? Here is why. Once in a while we perform so called "squash" migrations. A squash migration means that all migrations and model snapshot are deleted and a new initial migration and a model snapshot are generated based on the current state of all C# classes in a model.

Since a squash migration can be created at some moment in time within a development cycle (say, a week or a month) and there are multiple environments involved (e.g., `development`, `production`), this opens a possibility that some extra migration could've been applied and / or created in one of the environments before or after the squash migration.

1. If there is a migration **before** a squash migration and it has not been applied to the database yet, then it is easy to detect, because the model snapshot does not match the database and that can be easily checked by iterating over all tables and all columns.
2. However, if there is a migration **after** a squash migration, then current model snapshot reflects the changes made in that second migration (`SecondMigration`) whereas the model snapshot if only `InitialMigration` were applied matches the database. Subsequently, I need to compare the database with the model snapshot as if only `InitialMigration` were applied. If they match then, I do not have scenario #1 described above and it is safe to proceed with the squash migration and subsequent migration(s) and if they don't, then I have a migration before squash migration and which was not applied to the database.

**The "ugly" way that I have in mind is as follows**:

1. Drop if exists / create another database, call it `MyDatabaseSnapshot`, by running (via C# code) `Update-Database -m:Initial`. That will create a database with only `Initial` migration applied. The name of the initial migration is always the same, regardless how many times we re-generate squash migrations.
2. Then I can compare my database, call it `MyDatabase`, with `MyDatabaseSnapshot` using SQL. The SQL is straightforward but tedious. In any case, I already have it.

I wonder if it is possible to perform the same without creating that extra database. I'd appreciate any ideas.